# Drawing Bitmap as MainScreen Background. How to Stretch Image?

Tags: blackberry, background-image

I want the background image to stretch all screen. I simply created a VerticalFieldManager and modified paint method.

```
   verticalFieldManager = new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH
                            | VerticalFieldManager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR) {
             public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
                    graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(),
                                        backgroundBitmap, 0, 0);
                    super.paint(graphics);
        }

    };
```

And when i add a ListField to the verticalFieldManager and scroll, background image is not repaint. How can i repaint background when scroll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `EncodedImage` from your `Bitmap`, or even directly extract `EncodedImage` from resources - `EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("res/bg.png")`.

Then use this to scale it:

```
public static EncodedImage resize(EncodedImage eImage, int toWidth, 
        int toHeight, boolean keepAspectRatio) {

    int scaleX = Fixed32.div(
        Fixed32.toFP(eImage.getWidth()),
        Fixed32.toFP(toWidth)
    );

    int scaleY = Fixed32.div(
        Fixed32.toFP(eImage.getHeight()), 
        Fixed32.toFP(toHeight)
    );

    if (keepAspectRatio) {
        int scale = (scaleX > scaleY) ? scaleX : scaleY;
        return eImage.scaleImage32(scale, scale);
    } else {
        return eImage.scaleImage32(scaleX, scaleY);
    }
}
```

Then you may draw the `EncodedImage` on the `Graphics` object:

```
graphics.drawImage(
    0, 0, 
    encodedImage.getScaledWidth(), ncodedImage.getScaledHeight(), 
    encodedImage, 0, 0, 0
);
```

Comment: Fantastic, it works. Thank you very much Arhimed.

Could you help me on ListField scroll problem? When i scroll, background image is scrolling too. Should i repaint background image when scroll event occur?

Comment: Oh no. When i use this code, there is always a blank space after the last item of listview. That is not good.

Comment: To help with scrolling issue I need to experiment with the code. Sorry, experiment is not possible right now - I'm also under time pressure. However the idea for you to try is to shift starting Y coordinate for BG drawing on the same number of pixels as the current Ysroll (use `Manager.getVerticalScroll()`) of the container.

Comment: That blank space - can you determine which `Field` belongs that blank space? Is it blank space of the `ListField` or `VerticalFieldManager` or your screen's internal main manager? That the key point on what to fix.

Comment: I fix the white space issue.. 
But, `verticalFieldManager.getVerticalScroll();`  method in `paint` always return 0.

Comment: Sorry if my info was not helpful. Feel fry to uncheck the solution checkbox.